# System call fail "Incorrect Section Name -e" C++

Tags: c++, linux, dns, system

I'm trying to to update a DNS using a C++ code. My method is to use a string with a pipe with nsupdate.

When i call my system with "echo -e "" the trace file says "incorrect section name -e, and i don't understand what is the problem because if i paste the string into my linux terminal, it add correctly the DNS record.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "echo -e \"update add " << enumName << ".";
oss << m_configuration.m_zone << ". ";
oss << m_configuration.m_ttl << " NAPTR ";
oss << m_configuration.m_priority << " ";
oss << m_configuration.m_weight << " ";
oss << "\\\"S\\\" ";
oss << "\\\"" << boost::to_upper_copy<std::string>(service) <<m_configuration.m_serviceSuffix << "\\\" ";
oss << "\\\"" << m_configuration.m_regex << "\\\" ";
oss << "_" << service << "._" << m_configuration.m_srvRecord << "." << m_configuration.m_zone << ".\\n";
oss << "send\\nquit\" | nsupdate -l -v";
std::string msg = oss.str();
TRACE_DEBUG("msg: '%s'", msg.c_str());
 res = (system((msg).c_str()) == 0);
```

the Trace Debug shows msg and when i paste msg on my terminal it works... but the Jenkins debugger shows this : "incorrect section name: -e
syntax error"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you might have a different shell in your terminal and the one that `system` calls. This may result with the shells invoking a different `echo`. On most shells `echo` is builtin. Also, it is possible that on your terminal `echo` is an alias or a function.

Comment: Also, using shell this way is very dangerous. Please read about [command/shell injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection)

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I know about command injection but this is the only way i'm founding to do this.
About the echo, on my shell it works perfectly so i don't understand how the echo called by the system can be different ? I don't even understand the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `system` calls `/bin/sh` instead of `$SHELL` like your terminal. Some `/bin/sh` implementations will simply echo the characters `-e` just like any other text that the builtin `echo` will print to stdout. This `-e` is passed to `nsupdate` as is, and confuses it. This confusion causes the error.

The correct solution is to avoid using `system` altogether, and especially avoid constructing a string that you pass to `echo`. Of course, you can use `/bin/echo` if you want to avoid the builtin `echo`, but using `echo` in this manner is not advised in order to avoid [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).

A better solution would be to either one of:

1. put the text into a file and use `/bin/cat`, or simply use `<some_temp_file` to redirect the input. Using a file, safely, is tricky. Someone might read sensitive data, or manipulate the file, unless you do it right.
2. Use `popen` instead of system, only calling `/usr/bin/nsupdate -l -v`
3. Use `fork` and one of `execve` variants, only calling `/usr/bin/nsupdate -l -v`.

Note, use full path `/usr/bin/nsupdate` and don't rely on PATH, since PATH could be manipulated by a malicious third party.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution using full path of echo and it worked (went through escape keys problem tho)
I'm surprised to know that system call is not the same on the regular shell, thanks for telling me this.